# Jquery,saving the last dropped position of the draggable element

Tags: jquery

I have multiple dragging element and when page loads, the objects get placed in their default position(topmost of the webpage). I am dragging the elements and then saving their current position using offset().top and offset().left in the database. Then css will be updated by taking these values from the database and the elements will be placed on their respective position.

But again after  submitting the form, if I am dragging the element once again it is not calculating the coordinates as per the last dropped position but calculating as per the default position.

So,can anybody please help me to find the last dropped position and save it in the database. Thank you

Comment: what you are doing to store coordinates in database means you are using ajax to store values?

Comment: @WisdmLabs..Yes I am using ajax

Comment: I will recommend to use file handling to create .css file that will be generated from .php file and put values in coordinates in that .css file means write css in that file with coordinates and include that file using link tag in your index page

Comment: @WisdmLabs.. Can u please be more clear.. I am getting the coordinates from the database and dynamically generating its css in .php file.

Comment: in .php use file handling and create a .css file and use that css in your page

Comment: @WisdmLabs.. I will try .